# Is there a way of quickly indexing a size by size box for each element inside of 2D square tensor?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, pytorch

Say I have a (N, N) sized 2D square numpy array. I want to quickly find the neighboring square around each index in this array, and store it in a (N, N, 2 * size + 1, 2 * size + 1) tensor. Elements on the edges of the tensor should wrap around to the other side of the array. How can I do this quickly?

The solution I currently have involves padding the array by size, and then iterating through all the original elements on by one and getting the (size, size) subarray at each position. This is quite slow though, O(N^2) as we have to iterate through each index in the subarray. Is there a convenient indexing technique or numpy method that can do this operation, but faster?

I've looked for specific convolution methods online but no luck.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow--please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with what you've already tried, a sample input, and expected output.

Comment: try sliding windows view: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html

Comment: Depending what you want to do with the neighbors. In general, sliding windows is what you need. However, if you only want to do one operation on each windows, e.g. sum of elements, then you only need convolution.

Comment: Sliding windows isn't going to help with wrapping around rows and columns.  You probably need another data structure than a `numpy` array to get that functionality in an efficient manner.

Comment: @DanielF, he seems to have handled the wrapping by padding.  I believe `np.pad` has such a `wrap` mode.

Comment: Thanks, sliding windows was what I was looking for!